# Whats most pythonic way of colelcting second object of tuple in dictionary into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following objects

```
a = ("one", 1)
b = ("two", 2)
c = ("seven", 7)
my_dict = {10: a, 20:b, 70:c}
```

I want to get a list of `[1, 2, 7]` from `my_dict`. Whats the most pythonic way to do so?

Comment: so your my_dict actual is ```{10:("one",1), 20:("two",2), 70:("seven",7)}```, which tell @David and @Samwise
  are both right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use list comprehension. It's the most pythonic way of doing most things ;)

```py
output = [x[1] for x in my_dict.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like the functional way, you could use:

```
list(zip(*my_dict.values()))[1]
```

Output: `(1, 2, 7)`

Or, as list:

```
list(list(zip(*my_dict.values()))[1])
```

Output: `[1, 2, 7]`

Comment: creates a bunch of intermediate data structures for no reason - wasteful

Comment: @wim you're probably right, I still found it fun to show ;)

Comment: The functional approach is always more fun.

Comment: @ddejohn `[x[1] for x in my_dict.values()]` is already "functional"

Comment: I was referring to function composition, specifically my deleted approach which was downvoted for some reason lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple unpacking inside the list comprehension to avoid having to index into the tuple:

```py
result = [item for _, item in my_dict.values()]
print(result)
```

This prints:

```py
[1, 2, 7]
```